# PHP MySQL INSERT Query & PHP seems to be run twice

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make simple login server for android.

Login feature works well, but in registration has some problem.

My intent is :

1. Android Client Send User Info(id, username, password) to XAMPP Server by using HTTPPOST.
2. Server get User Info, and find repetition id or username from database(using select query). if repetition exists, response to client using echo.
3. if repetition not exists, make new user info to database using insert query. And response to client using echo.

If repetition exists, it works well. server response correctly.

but in case of no repetition, query's output is 1 then server response 'there is repetition'...

login.php is same code with register.php, but there is no insert query in login.php, and it works perfectly well.

so I think this problem caused by insert query.

here is my code:

```
<?php
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="mydatabase";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";
$id_localhost ="";

$localhost = mysql_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost, $id_localhost) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db($database_localhost, $localhost);

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$query_search = "select * from tbl_user where username = '".$username."' OR id = '".$id."'";
$query_exec = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_exec);

if($rows == 0) { 
    $query_register = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (id, username, password) VALUES ('$id', '$username', '$password')";
    $result = mysql_query($query_register) or die(mysql_error());
    if($result == TRUE){
        echo "Register Success";
    } else {
        echo "Register Fail";
    }
    exit;
    die;
} else {
    echo "Registered Device or Username";
    exit;
}
?>
```

login.php is almost same. only search query(select id and username and password same) and insert query is different(no insert in login.php).

server response is wrong but insert action is doing right. I can see new record in my database. so... it seems to be run twice.

client side has no problem because it also almost same with login code(And login works well with no insert query:)).

Comment: It's better to use `$username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';`. You'll avoid PHP Errors if the $_POST array doesn't contain a key named `username`. Also, you should use [MySQLi](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp) instead of MySQL. Your code isn't secure against a SQL injection.

Comment: I can't find an error in your code. The code can't run twice, unless there's a loop somewhere. You should display the PHP errors if there's any.

Comment: No error in code, feature works well, but wrong response.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

mysql_num_rows return an int, you are checking if $rows is false instead of 0. Use `===`.

---

What `id` are you referring to in your `tbl_user` and why would the user supply their ID? Are you sure that you are checking for the right `id`? It feels like you should be doing a separate query for the device id OR check for a `device_id` column in the table `tbl_user`.

**Other things to look into**

`exit;` and `die;` are the same so calling it twice makes no sense.

`if ($rows == 0)` is checking for `(bool) false` instead of the integer `0`. Use `===` for checking for supplied type.

When using "" double-quotation marks you can supply the variables directly;
E.g. `"...WHERE username = '$username'"` instead of `"... WHERE username = '".$username."'"`.

Look into using `mysqli` instead of `mysql` for more features and improved security; http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: I know exit; and die; are same. It is mistake. id means device id and it send automatically, user send his account name(username) and password to server. thank you for advice but i still can't understand why it works wrong :((

Comment: Have you tried altering the `if ($rows == 0)` to `if ($rows === 0)`?

Comment: What error are you getting? `echo "Register Fail";` or `echo "Registered Device or Username";`?

Comment: client always get "Registered Device or Username". but if no repetition in database(both id and username), record registered in database

Comment: How is that not working correctly then? If there is nothing in the database it's registered otherwise you get an error saying that there already is a user or device with supplied information. Sounds right to me.

Comment: i think this problem solved by this logic : set username and id to unique value in database setting. and no matter repetition exist, execute insert query. if there is repetition, die(mysql_erroe()); will excuted, client can use exception(no response)

Comment: That sounds like a bad solution to your problem. I am trying to wrap my head around what you want. Walk this through with me. I am your user. 1. I go to register.php and type my information. 2. I click submit and the form doesn't find my information so I get registered. 3. I get the message 'Register Success'. 4. I'm a happy man.

Comment: I think correctly working is it : if no repetition->register to db. and response 'registration success or fail'. repetition exist->response 'repetition is exist'. but now, 'no repetition' -> register to db and response 'repetition is exist'. repetition exist -> response 'repetition exist'.

Comment: $query_register = "INSERT INTO tbl_user (id, username, password) VALUES ('$id', '$username', '$password')";
 $result = mysql_query($query_register);
 if($result == TRUE){
  echo "Register Success";
    } else {
  echo "Register Fail";
    }

Comment: OMG it is similar to original problem... response is always "register fail"

Comment: I'm sorry to you it's time to sleep here(Korea, AM 12:10). I'll take this problem myself with your advice. thank you:)